# dynamic query for the alias row

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
--DISTINCT
organizations.Name,users.FName, users.LName, UserTypes.Name, users.Email, Users.id,
(SELECT COUNT(MessageId)) As MsgsReceived,
(SELECT COUNT(MessageID)
WHERE Messages.Urgency = 1) AS LowMsgsReceived,
(SELECT COUNT(MessageID)
WHERE Messages.Urgency = 2) AS MedMsgsReceived,
(SELECT COUNT(MessageID)
WHERE Messages.Urgency = 3) AS HighMsgsReceived
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Recipients ON
Users.ID = Recipients.UserId
INNER JOIN Messages ON
Messages.ID = Recipients.MessageID
INNER JOIN UserTypes ON
Users.UserTypeID = UserTypes.ID
INNER JOIN Organizations ON
Users.OrganizationId = Organizations.Id
GROUP BY organizations.Name,users.FName, users.LName, UserTypes.Name, users.Email, Users.id, Messages.Urgency
ORDER BY Users.FName
```

The count give me wrong result of the level of message received. The below query give me the count correctly but some of the row i dont want to display null on it,display 0 instead, any help ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to bind child table with parent table"? Which table is the child? Which table is the parent? On what conditions do you need them bound?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     Select u.fname, u.lName, u.Id,
        Count(m.Id) messagesRecvd,
        Sum(Case m.Urgency When 1 Then 1 End) LowMsgsRecvd,
        Sum(Case m.Urgency When 2 Then 1 End) MedMsgsRecvd,
        Sum(Case m.Urgency When 3 Then 1 End) HighMsgsRecvd
     From users u
        Left Join (Messages m Join Recipients r
                       On r.MessageId = m.Id)
            On r.UserId = u.Id
     Group By u.fname, u.lName, u.Id
     Order by u.fName
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, your answer output similar to mine, but how to bind child table with parent table ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
SELECT      --DISTINCT
            organizations.Name
            , users.FName
            , users.LName
            , UserTypes.Name
            , users.Email
            , Users.id
            , COUNT(MessageId) As MsgsReceived
            , SUM(CASE WHEN Messages.Urgency = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LowMsgsReceived
            , SUM(CASE WHEN Messages.Urgency = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MedMsgsReceived
            , SUM(CASE WHEN Messages.Urgency = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HighMsgsReceived
FROM        Users
            INNER JOIN Recipients
                ON Users.ID = Recipients.UserId
            INNER JOIN Messages
                ON Messages.ID = Recipients.MessageID
            INNER JOIN UserTypes
                ON Users.UserTypeID = UserTypes.ID
            INNER JOIN Organizations
                ON Users.OrganizationId = Organizations.Id
GROUP BY    organizations.Name
            ,users.FName
            , users.LName
            , UserTypes.Name
            , users.Email
            , Users.id
            , Messages.Urgency
ORDER BY    Users.FName
```